# Stack Exchange 2.0 sites not mentioned in attribution notice of Stack Exchange data dumps

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, data-dump, closed-sites

Looking at the data dump for the recently closed Freelancers Stack Exchange beta, I note the license.txt file reads:

> So let me clarify what we mean by attribution. If you republish this content, we *require* that you:
>
> 1. Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow, Stack Overflow Meta, Server Fault, or Super User in some way. It doesn#t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
>
> ...

Since this is in the clarification part of the attribution requirement, rather than the license requirement itself (i.e., the assertion of CC-WIKI), the omission of any reference to the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites is a minor point, but it might suggest to pernickety readers that the wrong license text has been bundled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the text file existed before Stack Exchange 2.0 existed, and was not updated to reflect.

The two most recent data dumps have a corrected file that references the whole network and not just the trilogy + MSO.

Answer (score 1):

I've put some static pages up with the content of the failed Freelancers Meta, with a discussion of the license page at:

http://www.textproof.com/ar/freelancers-meta/license.html

If there's anything that falls short of what I should do, please tell me. Otherwise, I suggest that what I did is a reasonable interpretation of the license, given problems applying the rule to link to users' pages on Stack Overflow, etc.